# Recover Ubuntu Hard Drive

Tags: boot, hard-drive, data-recovery

I rebooted my Ubuntu on a virtual machine by mistake during OS upgrade. Now it doesn't start from the hard drive, it shows Ubuntu logo and then stuck in a black screen. I booted from the CD. How can I access my hard drive to recover files? It is not seen in the list of devices, while "fdisk -l" shows it as /dev/sda and "fsck -N" shows it's filesystem type ask ext2.

Comment: A hard reboot? i.e. you pressed the Power Off button or unplugged the power? Then the partition may be badly damaged if you do not see it. Does it appear in `sudo fdisk -l` or `lsblk -f`?

Comment: Rebooted how?   If you're like me and reboot via sysrq/reisub or equiv. (to ensure a save/clean dismount etc) it should boot.. if you didn't cleanly unmount drives then I'd check your *file-systems* for errors (ie. `fsck`).  You should be specific as to what command(s) it's not seen etc; also what release are you talking about (server?, desktop?, core? etc)   Does it boot to runlevel 1?

Comment: @vanadium rebooted the VM where Ubuntu is installed. with "sudo fdisk -l" the disk is seen as /dev/sda with the proper size, thanks! Now how to mount it?

Comment: Is this an Ubuntu in a virtual machine? Clarify your situation - use "edit"

Comment: @vanadium - done, edited